# Tag synonyms for [optimization] and [sql-server]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I would like to propose the following tag synonyms:

- [effeciency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effeciency) (7) -> [optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) (25)
- [mssql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql) (3) -> [sql-server](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) (4)

In the latter case, I think [sql-server](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) should be the master as [mssql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql) looks too similar to [mysql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed. Although you'd think "effeciency" would at least be spelled right... :)